# Keeping track of data types in Python

Tags: python, types

So I hope this is a valid question... I've recently (today actually) decided to learn how a scripting language, so I chose Python. While glancing over code, I felt overwhelmed, and I soon realized that the reason was that I didn't know *what* data type conversions and stuff were going on.

My question is: Is there any convention of keeping track of what the data type is? I come from more of a C background, so I find this quite confusing. Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal Python approach is `duck typing` -- from the old phrase "if it quacks like a duck, and walks like a duck, it's duck enough for me".

In exceptional cases where you really *must* check what type something is (to do different things to otherwise similar types... usually not a good idea), that's what [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=isinstance#isinstance) is for.

`isinstance` used to be considered a last-ditch measure, with serious warnings against overusing it... but while the gist of that classic tirade remains valid, since Python 2.6 it has acquired an important proviso: while checking if something is an instance of a specific concrete class remains in the "rarely a good idea" category, checking if it's an instance of an [abstract base class](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#abcs-abstract-base-classes) (aka ABC) is a more frequently useful idea, because it just offers a nice and flexible way to check if something implements or not some interface.

For example, to check if an object is callable, one used to have to do something like:

```
if hasattr(type(obj), '__call__'): ...
```

Since 2.6, the preferred alternative has become:

```
import collections
if isinstance(obj, collections.Callable): ...
```

much more direct and cleaner.  Richer ABCs such as, e.g., `collections.MutableSequence`, which imply the existence and coordination of many different methods, make this exponentially stronger.

The fact that checking (with `isinstance`) the membership in a concrete type is not so good, while checking the membership in an ABC is more often useful, lies in a principle that the "Gang of 4" expressed clearly and intensely in the first part of their wonderful book "Design Patterns" (in a mostly C++ context, but it really applies much more widely than that!): **program to an interface, not to an implementation**.

Checking membership of a concrete class indicates you're probably guilty of programming to an implementation; with an ABC, you're basically checking an interface, so many issues just aren't big problems any more (ABCs are more than just interfaces -- they can also offer "implementation help" to their concrete subclasses -- but, when we're talking about `isinstance`, thinking of them as interfaces is probably the most helpful stance).

Comment: From 'http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/duck_typing.shtml', it says 'The principle of duck typing says that you shouldn't care what type of object you have.' Is that true/what duck typing is?

Comment: @DMan, except that (to paraphrase the way that article puts it) you _do_ more often than not care about "what **interface** does the object implement" (the obj's concrete type is mostly about **how** it implements that interface... which indeed you shouldn't care about).  In C there is no direct equivalent, but in C++ there are templates to implement generic programming, and they're really very close to a duck typing approach (except that they're applied at compile time, rather than at runtime as dynamic languages do;-).

Comment: I just wanted to add that this was a brilliantly concise answer to a very complex problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `isinstance(object, classinfo)` and `type(object)`.

- http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type
- http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: I should of phrased my question a little different- I mean keeping track of the type at a glance- like see I added _int to all integers.